# How to create one array from two regular array in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am having an array of some section and units for a course, Section are non numeric and units are numeric id generated from wordpress.

Array containing both section and units is like :- `(a,1,2,3,b,4,5,6,7,c,8,9,10)`

I want to make it like this `$combine_array= ( a=> '1,2,3', b=> '4,5,6,7' c=> '8,9,10' )`

Comment: how you are separating it to make what the logic behind `$combine_array= (
a=> '1,2,3',
b=> '4,5,6,7'
c=> '8,9,10'
)`   this part is not clear .

Comment: This is what I am looking for

Comment: you can't ask a question that you don't know the logic behind it! what is it going to do? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am asking, on the basis of what you are making these pairs ??

Comment: I want to combine these two arrays in one array like $combine_array= (
a=> '1,2,3',
b=> '4,5,6,7'
c=> '8,9,10'
)

Comment: @AlaaA.F. please try to become little more gentle, SO is new may be he is not too comfortable here to express himself/herself.

Comment: @user3392190 please let me know, on the basis of what you are making this pairing ?

Comment: the only basic is numeric and non numeric

Comment: but how you are placing `1,2,3` and `a` as key and value pair ??

Comment: This is what we needed to do.

Comment: one the basis of what you want `a` and `1, 2, 3`  as key and balue, how they are related ?? for example  considering  1,2,3 as some people  belongs to one city ?? like this ??

Comment: how `1, 2, 3` are related to `a` please let us know answer for this question by editing your question .

Comment: no other relation in that except that

Comment: why `4,5,6` are not related to `a` or `c` ??

Comment: I am having one array of both numeric values and non_numeric values in combined form like `(a,1,2,3,b,4,5,6,7,c,8,9,10)` and I want to make it like this $combine_array= (
a=> '1,2,3',
b=> '4,5,6,7'
c=> '8,9,10'
)

Comment: why `123` for `a` and not for `b` or `c` ?? or why `a` does not contain `4, 5` they are also numeric and `a` is numeric .

Comment: Actually I am having an array of some section and units for a course, Now Section are non numeric  and units are numeric id generated from wordpress. now I want to separate related units for sections

Comment: then add that part, ho the sections and units are related and other needed information. Your question is too unclear for people to understand, more than 44 peoples have already visited this page, but you are getting no solution, that is already suggesting you to edit your question.

Comment: you are getting `(a,1,2,3,b,4,5,6,7,c,8,9,10)` as one array ?? if yes, this makes sense .

Comment: what will happen  if the first element will be a numeric one ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, next time try to be more clear about what you are asking - right now no-one knows what are your criteria for combining those array.

From what I gathered from your comments at the beggining you have array like `$array = array( 'a', 1, 2, 3, 'b', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'c', 8, 9, 10 );`, then you what to combine it to multi-dimension array where keys will be non-numeric values from array `$array` and values will be the numeric keys, am I right?

You can achive it very simply with `foreach` loop. Firstly create new array, then go in loop through all your values from `$array` and check if value is numeric or not - if it's not numeric save it to some helper variable and add all numeric values into that key.

```php
$helper = false;
$combined = array();
$array = array( 'a', 1, 2, 3, 'b', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'c', 8, 9, 10 );

foreach($array as $value){
    if(is_string( $value )){
        $helper = $value;
    } else {
        $combined[ $helper ][] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump( $combined );
```

Comment: One quick note is you can prefer `is_string()` in place of `!is_int()` here.

Comment: what will happen when the first element is numeric ??

Comment: First element is non_numeric every time

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu switched to is_string, thanks. SO says that first element is always non-numeric so no need to look for that variant.

Comment: but there is another question , what will happen when the first element is numeric ??

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu It will be added to key `0`. Why 0? Because `$helper` is set to `false` on default. When `false` is used as an array key it will be converted to `0` as it is one of two non-Boolean values which evaluates to `false` and can be used as array keys. Please read the section on [Booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more information.

Comment: Have tested what you are saying ? ty with `$array = array( 34,'a', 1, 2, 3, 'b', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'c', 8, 9, 10 );` .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Yes, I did. It's actually pretty logic that it will work this way. Your example: http://ideone.com/Ejc2ZG

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I know, you asked for that example.

Comment: yes, that is why I asked OP to clear it and he did not replied and there were two down votes, so might be it will be deleted, so I upvoted it, so that we can know how complex it can be ? sadly no reply or edit from OP .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu OP cleared it in this very topic - just look at the comment from Mar 29 at 13:07 (3rd from top).

Comment: what I am saying is when the first element is numerical, we are unable to keep the key as non-numeric, what he wants there.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu But he said that first element **is always** non-numeric. You asked what will happen when first element is numeric and I gave you an answer. Answer is complete and marked as accepted.

Comment: yes, I know answer is complete and mark as accepted. I am not asking anyone to undo that :D

Answer (score 0):

I have kept all the elements which are not string in another array `$b`,  now tell me in this condition where you want to store those elements ??

```
$helper = false;
$combo = array();
$array = array( 34,'a', 1, 2, 3, 'b', 4, 5, 6, 7, 'c', 8, 9, 10 );
$b = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    //if(!is_int( $value )){ // if there is any other element beside string and you want to make them key 
    if(is_string( $value )){
        $helper = $value;
    } else {
        if($helper){
            $combo [ $helper ][] = $value;
        } else {
            $b[] = $value;
        }
    }
}

var_dump( $combo );
var_dump($b);
```

### output

```
array (size=3)
  'a' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 3
  'b' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 4
      1 => int 5
      2 => int 6
      3 => int 7
  'c' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => int 8
      1 => int 9
      2 => int 10
array (size=1)
  0 => int 34
```